# Почему не работает клавиша Tab?

Tags: emacs

Клавиша TAB в emacs не работает вообще.
И табуляция, конечно, тоже. 
С-h k выдает - < tab > runs the command yas-expand, which is an alias for - для какой-то команды в yasnippet.el.
Я хочу переназначить и не могу

```
(global-set-key (kdb "tab") 'indent-for-tab-command)
```

Когда выполняю мне пишут, что symbols function definition is void: kdb.
Пробовала "< tab >", "TAB", "Tab", "", "tab" - результат один и тот же.
Что можно еще попробовать?

Comment: Попробуйте [это](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabKey) (очепятка у вас)

Comment: Ха! (global-set-key [tab] 'tab-to-tab-stop) - это работает! спасибо!

Comment: Да и первый вариант работал бы (наверно)), если бы вы не опечатались: `kbd` vs `kdb`

Comment: Вряд ли `global-set-key` для <TAB> это хорошая идея. Просто посмотрите на разнообразие binding этого символа в разных major mode и задумайтесь.